# Kong-ingress-controller CrashLoopBackOff : "kong-proxy" is forbidden

Tags: kubernetes, kong-ingress

I've installed `kong-ingress-controller` using yaml file on a 3-nodes k8s cluster.
but I'm getting this (the status of pod is `CrashLoopBackOff`):

```
$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                        READY   STATUS             RESTARTS         AGE
kong          ingress-kong-74d8d78f57-57fqr               1/2     CrashLoopBackOff   12 (3m23s ago)   40m
[...]
```

there are 2 container declarations in kong yaml file: `proxy` and `ingress-controller`.
The first one is up and running but the `ingress-controller` container is not:

```
$kubectl describe pod ingress-kong-74d8d78f57-57fqr -n kong |less

[...]
  ingress-controller:
    Container ID:   docker://8e9a3370f78b3057208b943048c9ecd51054d0b276ef6c93ccf049093261d8de
    Image:          kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller:1.3
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller@sha256:cff0df9371d5ad07fef406c356839736ce9eeb0d33f918f56b1b232cd7289207
    Port:           8080/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Tue, 07 Sep 2021 17:15:54 +0430
      Finished:     Tue, 07 Sep 2021 17:15:54 +0430
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  13
    Liveness:       http-get http://:10254/healthz delay=5s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:      http-get http://:10254/healthz delay=5s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      CONTROLLER_KONG_ADMIN_URL:              https://127.0.0.1:8444
      CONTROLLER_KONG_ADMIN_TLS_SKIP_VERIFY:  true
      CONTROLLER_PUBLISH_SERVICE:             kong/kong-proxy
      POD_NAME:                               ingress-kong-74d8d78f57-57fqr (v1:metadata.name)
      POD_NAMESPACE:                          kong (v1:metadata.namespace)
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-ft7gg (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-ft7gg:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                  From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                 ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  46m                  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned kong/ingress-kong-74d8d78f57-57fqr to kung-node-2
  Normal   Pulled     46m                  kubelet            Container image "kong:2.5" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    46m                  kubelet            Created container proxy
  Normal   Started    46m                  kubelet            Started container proxy
  Normal   Pulled     45m (x4 over 46m)    kubelet            Container image "kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller:1.3" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    45m (x4 over 46m)    kubelet            Created container ingress-controller
  Normal   Started    45m (x4 over 46m)    kubelet            Started container ingress-controller
  Warning  BackOff    87s (x228 over 46m)  kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container
```

And here is the log of `ingress-controller` container:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Kong Ingress controller
  Release:
  Build:
  Repository:
  Go:         go1.16.7
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

W0907 12:56:12.940106       1 client_config.go:614] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
time="2021-09-07T12:56:12Z" level=info msg="version of kubernetes api-server: 1.22" api-server-host="https://10.*.*.1:443" git_commit=632ed300f2c34f6d6d15ca4cef3d3c7073412212 git_tree_state=clean git_version=v1.22.1 major=1 minor=22 platform=linux/amd64
time="2021-09-07T12:56:12Z" level=fatal msg="failed to fetch publish-service: services \"kong-proxy\" is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:kong:kong-serviceaccount\" cannot get resource \"services\" in API group \"\" in the namespace \"kong\"" service_name=kong-proxy service_namespace=kong
```

If someone could help me to get a solution, that would be awesome.

============================================================

**UPDATE**:

The `kong-ingress-controller`'s yaml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: kong
---
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: kongclusterplugins.configuration.konghq.com
spec:
  additionalPrinterColumns:
  - JSONPath: .plugin
    description: Name of the plugin
    name: Plugin-Type
    type: string
  - JSONPath: .metadata.creationTimestamp
    description: Age
    name: Age
    type: date
  - JSONPath: .disabled
    description: Indicates if the plugin is disabled
    name: Disabled
    priority: 1
    type: boolean
  - JSONPath: .config
    description: Configuration of the plugin
    name: Config
    priority: 1
    type: string
  group: configuration.konghq.com
  names:
    kind: KongClusterPlugin
    plural: kongclusterplugins
    shortNames:
    - kcp
  scope: Cluster
  subresources:
    status: {}
  validation:
    openAPIV3Schema:
      properties:
        config:
          type: object
        configFrom:
          properties:
            secretKeyRef:
              properties:
                key:
                  type: string
                name:
                  type: string
                namespace:
                  type: string
              required:
              - name
              - namespace
              - key
              type: object
          type: object
        disabled:
          type: boolean
        plugin:
          type: string
        protocols:
          items:
            enum:
            - http
            - https
            - grpc
            - grpcs
            - tcp
            - tls
            type: string
          type: array
        run_on:
          enum:
          - first
          - second
          - all
          type: string
      required:
      - plugin
  version: v1
---
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: kongconsumers.configuration.konghq.com
spec:
  additionalPrinterColumns:
  - JSONPath: .username
    description: Username of a Kong Consumer
    name: Username
    type: string
  - JSONPath: .metadata.creationTimestamp
    description: Age
    name: Age
    type: date
  group: configuration.konghq.com
  names:
    kind: KongConsumer
    plural: kongconsumers
    shortNames:
    - kc
  scope: Namespaced
  subresources:
    status: {}
  validation:
    openAPIV3Schema:
      properties:
        credentials:
          items:
            type: string
          type: array
        custom_id:
          type: string
        username:
          type: string
  version: v1
---
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: kongingresses.configuration.konghq.com
spec:
  group: configuration.konghq.com
  names:
    kind: KongIngress
    plural: kongingresses
    shortNames:
    - ki
  scope: Namespaced
  subresources:
    status: {}
  validation:
    openAPIV3Schema:
      properties:
        proxy:
          properties:
            connect_timeout:
              minimum: 0
              type: integer
            path:
              pattern: ^/.*$
              type: string
            protocol:
              enum:
              - http
              - https
              - grpc
              - grpcs
              - tcp
              - tls
              type: string
            read_timeout:
              minimum: 0
              type: integer
            retries:
              minimum: 0
              type: integer
            write_timeout:
              minimum: 0
              type: integer
          type: object
        route:
          properties:
            headers:
              additionalProperties:
                items:
                  type: string
                type: array
              type: object
            https_redirect_status_code:
              type: integer
            methods:
              items:
                type: string
              type: array
            path_handling:
              enum:
              - v0
              - v1
              type: string
            preserve_host:
              type: boolean
            protocols:
              items:
                enum:
                - http
                - https
                - grpc
                - grpcs
                - tcp
                - tls
                type: string
              type: array
            regex_priority:
              type: integer
            request_buffering:
              type: boolean
            response_buffering:
              type: boolean
            snis:
              items:
                type: string
              type: array
            strip_path:
              type: boolean
        upstream:
          properties:
            algorithm:
              enum:
              - round-robin
              - consistent-hashing
              - least-connections
              type: string
            hash_fallback:
              type: string
            hash_fallback_header:
              type: string
            hash_on:
              type: string
            hash_on_cookie:
              type: string
            hash_on_cookie_path:
              type: string
            hash_on_header:
              type: string
            healthchecks:
              properties:
                active:
                  properties:
                    concurrency:
                      minimum: 1
                      type: integer
                    healthy:
                      properties:
                        http_statuses:
                          items:
                            type: integer
                          type: array
                        interval:
                          minimum: 0
                          type: integer
                        successes:
                          minimum: 0
                          type: integer
                      type: object
                    http_path:
                      pattern: ^/.*$
                      type: string
                    timeout:
                      minimum: 0
                      type: integer
                    unhealthy:
                      properties:
                        http_failures:
                          minimum: 0
                          type: integer
                        http_statuses:
                          items:
                            type: integer
                          type: array
                        interval:
                          minimum: 0
                          type: integer
                        tcp_failures:
                          minimum: 0
                          type: integer
                        timeout:
                          minimum: 0
                          type: integer
                      type: object
                  type: object
                passive:
                  properties:
                    healthy:
                      properties:
                        http_statuses:
                          items:
                            type: integer
                          type: array
                        interval:
                          minimum: 0
                          type: integer
                        successes:
                          minimum: 0
                          type: integer
                      type: object
                    unhealthy:
                      properties:
                        http_failures:
                          minimum: 0
                          type: integer
                        http_statuses:
                          items:
                            type: integer
                          type: array
                        interval:
                          minimum: 0
                          type: integer
                        tcp_failures:
                          minimum: 0
                          type: integer
                        timeout:
                          minimum: 0
                          type: integer
                      type: object
                  type: object
                threshold:
                  type: integer
              type: object
            host_header:
              type: string
            slots:
              minimum: 10
              type: integer
          type: object
  version: v1
---
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: kongplugins.configuration.konghq.com
spec:
  additionalPrinterColumns:
  - JSONPath: .plugin
    description: Name of the plugin
    name: Plugin-Type
    type: string
  - JSONPath: .metadata.creationTimestamp
    description: Age
    name: Age
    type: date
  - JSONPath: .disabled
    description: Indicates if the plugin is disabled
    name: Disabled
    priority: 1
    type: boolean
  - JSONPath: .config
    description: Configuration of the plugin
    name: Config
    priority: 1
    type: string
  group: configuration.konghq.com
  names:
    kind: KongPlugin
    plural: kongplugins
    shortNames:
    - kp
  scope: Namespaced
  subresources:
    status: {}
  validation:
    openAPIV3Schema:
      properties:
        config:
          type: object
        configFrom:
          properties:
            secretKeyRef:
              properties:
                key:
                  type: string
                name:
                  type: string
              required:
              - name
              - key
              type: object
          type: object
        disabled:
          type: boolean
        plugin:
          type: string
        protocols:
          items:
            enum:
            - http
            - https
            - grpc
            - grpcs
            - tcp
            - tls
            type: string
          type: array
        run_on:
          enum:
          - first
          - second
          - all
          type: string
      required:
      - plugin
  version: v1
---
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: tcpingresses.configuration.konghq.com
spec:
  additionalPrinterColumns:
  - JSONPath: .status.loadBalancer.ingress[*].ip
    description: Address of the load balancer
    name: Address
    type: string
  - JSONPath: .metadata.creationTimestamp
    description: Age
    name: Age
    type: date
  group: configuration.konghq.com
  names:
    kind: TCPIngress
    plural: tcpingresses
  scope: Namespaced
  subresources:
    status: {}
  validation:
    openAPIV3Schema:
      properties:
        apiVersion:
          type: string
        kind:
          type: string
        metadata:
          type: object
        spec:
          properties:
            rules:
              items:
                properties:
                  backend:
                    properties:
                      serviceName:
                        type: string
                      servicePort:
                        format: int32
                        type: integer
                    type: object
                  host:
                    type: string
                  port:
                    format: int32
                    type: integer
                type: object
              type: array
            tls:
              items:
                properties:
                  hosts:
                    items:
                      type: string
                    type: array
                  secretName:
                    type: string
                type: object
              type: array
          type: object
        status:
          type: object
  version: v1beta1
status:
  acceptedNames:
    kind: ""
    plural: ""
  conditions: []
  storedVersions: []
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: kong-serviceaccount
  namespace: kong
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: kong-ingress-clusterrole
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - endpoints
  - nodes
  - pods
  - secrets
  verbs:
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - nodes
  verbs:
  - get
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - services
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - networking.k8s.io
  - extensions
  - networking.internal.knative.dev
  resources:
  - ingresses
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - events
  verbs:
  - create
  - patch
- apiGroups:
  - networking.k8s.io
  - extensions
  - networking.internal.knative.dev
  resources:
  - ingresses/status
  verbs:
  - update
- apiGroups:
  - configuration.konghq.com
  resources:
  - tcpingresses/status
  verbs:
  - update
- apiGroups:
  - configuration.konghq.com
  resources:
  - kongplugins
  - kongclusterplugins
  - kongcredentials
  - kongconsumers
  - kongingresses
  - tcpingresses
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - configmaps
  verbs:
  - create
  - get
  - update
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: kong-ingress-clusterrole-nisa-binding
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: kong-ingress-clusterrole
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: kong-serviceaccount
  namespace: kong
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tcp
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
  name: kong-proxy
  namespace: kong
spec:
  ports:
  - name: proxy
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8000
  - name: proxy-ssl
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8443
  selector:
    app: ingress-kong
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kong-validation-webhook
  namespace: kong
spec:
  ports:
  - name: webhook
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: ingress-kong
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: ingress-kong
  name: ingress-kong
  namespace: kong
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ingress-kong
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kuma.io/gateway: enabled
        prometheus.io/port: "8100"
        prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
        traffic.sidecar.istio.io/includeInboundPorts: ""
      labels:
        app: ingress-kong
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: KONG_PROXY_LISTEN
          value: 0.0.0.0:8000, 0.0.0.0:8443 ssl http2
        - name: KONG_PORT_MAPS
          value: 80:8000, 443:8443
        - name: KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN
          value: 127.0.0.1:8444 ssl
        - name: KONG_STATUS_LISTEN
          value: 0.0.0.0:8100
        - name: KONG_DATABASE
          value: "off"
        - name: KONG_NGINX_WORKER_PROCESSES
          value: "2"
        - name: KONG_ADMIN_ACCESS_LOG
          value: /dev/stdout
        - name: KONG_ADMIN_ERROR_LOG
          value: /dev/stderr
        - name: KONG_PROXY_ERROR_LOG
          value: /dev/stderr
        image: kong:2.5
        lifecycle:
          preStop:
            exec:
              command:
              - /bin/sh
              - -c
              - kong quit
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /status
            port: 8100
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        name: proxy
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
          name: proxy
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 8443
          name: proxy-ssl
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 8100
          name: metrics
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /status
            port: 8100
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
      - env:
        - name: CONTROLLER_KONG_ADMIN_URL
          value: https://127.0.0.1:8444
        - name: CONTROLLER_KONG_ADMIN_TLS_SKIP_VERIFY
          value: "true"
        - name: CONTROLLER_PUBLISH_SERVICE
          value: kong/kong-proxy
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        image: kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller:1.3
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 10254
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        name: ingress-controller
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: webhook
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 10254
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
      serviceAccountName: kong-serviceaccount
```

Comment: Upon further investigation into that repo, [1.x only works up to k8s 1.21](https://github.com/Kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller/issues/1703#issuecomment-899576883) so I'll delete my answer and you'll have to downgrade your cluster(!) or find an alternative Ingress controller

Comment: thanks for your time.
in the `RBAC` file you mentioned, I changed `apiVersion` from  `rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1` to  `rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1` and everything is working now.
But this method does not seem right so according to your comment I will downgrade the cluster.

Comment: @hesmoh could you post your findings as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Having analysed the comments it looks like changing `apiVersion` from `rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1` to `rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1` has solved the problem temporally, an alternative to this solution is to downgrade the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

I had installed `kubernetes:1.22` and tried to use `kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller:1.3` .

as @mdaniel said in the comment:

> Upon further investigation into that repo, 1.x only works up to k8s 1.21 so I'll delete my answer and you'll have to downgrade your cluster(!) or find an alternative Ingress controller

‌Based on documentation(you can find this at [KIC version compatibility](https://docs.konghq.com/kubernetes-ingress-controller/1.3.x/references/version-compatibility/)) :

[image: version compatibility]

As you can see, `Kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller` supports a maximum version of `1.21` of `kubernetes`(at the time of writing this answer). So I decided to downgrade my cluster to version `1.20` and this solved my problem.